# Connecting android device to Windows 10 in LAN

Tags: android, networking

I can connect through the Android Emulator without any problem by using my PC's IP address which is `192.168.197.1`. However I can't connect through my Android device where I need to test my app. I'm connected via wifi to my PC's router.

I have tried these addresses:

- `192.168.197.1`
- `192.168.197.1:8080`. I also tried to open the 8080 port on my Firewall, but when using `telnet` it still says connection failed.
- `10.0.2.2` with and without the port.
- I've also tried doing all this using port 80
- I've tried using usb tethering.
- I've tried connecting my PC trough a WiFi Hotspot in my Android device.

Nothing seems to work. Any ideas?

Comment: What exactly is the server that is running on the pc? Some Web app? A database?

Comment: You should run `ipconfig` on the PC and use whatever address that gives you along with whatever port number your server is listening on. If none of that works, I'm not sure what to tell you

Comment: Yes, I did that. The IPv4 address is `192.168.197.1`. Using an Android Emulator device I can access my local webserver perfectly fine. But using my actual Android device it doesn't work. Maybe I'm using the wrong port?  Where can I see which port my server uses?

Comment: If you can use that in the emulator as-is, then it's port 80, the default http port. Your phone must be in the same network as your pc, and if you are tethering, then the IP address is probably different than the one the emulator would use

Comment: @cricket_007 so I'm trying `192.168.197.1:80` on my Android device but the page keeps loading and nothing happens. My phone is connected via WiFi where as my PC is connected via Ethernet. Maybe I need to forward the port on my router, or it doesn't matter?

Comment: You couldve used `ipconfig /all` and looked at the DHCP address for your PC from there as well

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution for anyone having the same problem. You need to login to your router interface and find information about the connected devices. Mine was the "DHCP Information" tab. I found the IP address assigned to my PC (which was different than the one ipconfig gave me) and used that on my phone without the port number, to access the local server.